# Exception handling in a class C++

Tags: c++

I am going through Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ and I am facing an issue currently.
I am writing a stack class using arrays and the book suggests me to use exception specification in the function declaration. In my case I have StackEmptyException and StackFullException classes derived from RuntimeException class and the book says that I should not try to catch this exception in the function body but whenever I try to run my program forcing an exception it fails to start saying "Unhandled exception". I would like to understand where the problem comes from, because the book doesn't really explains it, only mentioning, thus I would appreciate any related answer. Here is my code:

```cpp
class RuntimeException {
private:
    string errMsg;
public:
    RuntimeException(const string& err) { errMsg = err; }
    string getMessage() const { return errMsg; }
};

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const RuntimeException& e){
    return out << e.getMessage();
}

class StackEmptyException : public RuntimeException {
public:
    StackEmptyException(const string& err) : RuntimeException(err) {}
};

class StackFullException : public RuntimeException {
public:
    StackFullException(const string& err) : RuntimeException(err) {}
};

template <typename Object>
class ArrayStack {
private:
    enum { CAPACITY = 1000 };
    int capacity;
    Object* S;
    int t;

public:
    ArrayStack(int cap = CAPACITY) {
        capacity = cap;
        S = new Object[capacity];
        t = -1;
    }

    int size() const { return t + 1; }
    bool isEmpty() const { return (t < 0); }

    // Passing the object by reference so that we could
    // edit its value    e.g. stack.top() = 10; would be valid
    Object& top() throw(StackEmptyException) { 
        if (isEmpty())
            throw StackEmptyException("Access to empty stack");
        return S[t];
    }

    void push(const Object& elem) throw(StackFullException) {
        if (size() == capacity)
            throw StackFullException("Stack overflow");
        S[++t] = elem;
    }

    // Not passing by reference, because we remove the last element
    // from the stack, thus we can not change its value 
    Object pop() throw(StackEmptyException) {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw StackEmptyException("Access to empty stack");
        return S[t--];
    }

    ArrayStack(const ArrayStack& st);               // Copy constructor
    ArrayStack& operator=(const ArrayStack& st);    // Assignment operator constructor
    ~ArrayStack() { delete[] S; }                   // Destructor

};
```

Comment: So how are you using this class? And where are you trying to catch the exception?

Comment: Just tried few scenarios in the main function and everything works well until I try to force an exception, for example if I start with stack.pop(); on a just-declared stack.

Comment: Well if you don't wrap the call to the function that can throw an exception in a `try` - `catch` block then the exception is unhandled. If I understood what the book said correctly (I haven't read the actual book, just going of your statement), then you should either wrap the calls to the member functions of the `ArrayStack` class in `try` - `catch` or the entire program (which would not really be a best practice as it would make it harder to figure out where exactly the exception occur)

Comment: Wrapped it in the functions bodies and everything is fine now. I'm feeling silly :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your book says you shouldn't always use a try/catch to catch this is because you should first do the bounds checking yourself.  So before you pop() check if isEmpty() first for example.